# Send email using content of a text file

Tags: vba, powershell

I'm hope to create a script which looks up a date in a text file and then send an email to the corresponding email address.  The text file would be structured something like this:

```
25/02/2018, blah@email.com
26/02/2018, blue@email.com
etc
```

This will be run on a Windows 2012 box so ideally i'd like to use powershell.  I don't want any reliance on a database so i thought a simple text file that could be searched may be the easiest way.  Essentially this will be used to send emails alerts for for certain events with the date being used to sent the email to the correct night duty staff.  Need to use a script as some of the apps that I hope to link it to have little to no notification options but they can invoke external scripts.

Any guidance gratefully received.

Thanks,
A

Comment: you can certainly do this with vba though perhaps you meant vbscript? If vba, is the reason for an external file because Excel/Access (insert other applicable application here) will not be used to run the vba script? Otherwise, have the lookup in the same document as the script.

Comment: While your question is of potential interest to future readers, it is generally expected that you've attempted a solution yourself and ask about where, specifically, you're stuck. 
Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad; here's the outline of a solution (run as a script file, PSv3+):

```
# Declare a parameter for the target date.
param(
  [datetime] $TargetDate = [datetime]::Today
)

# Format the target date as a string to match the input file's date format.
$targetDateFormatted = (Get-Date -Date $TargetDate -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy')

# Specify the input file (CSV format, as implied by your sample data).
$inputFile = 'DateEmail.csv'

Import-Csv -Header Date, Email $inputFile | 
  Where-Object Date -eq $targetDateFormatted | 
    ForEach-Object {

      Write-Verbose -Verbose "Date is $($_.Date); email address is $($_.Email)"

      # Invoke the Send-MailMessage cmdlet here.

    }
```